# Long directory listing

Tags: linux, unix

How do you perform a long directory listing of all files in the /bin directory that have exactly three characters in their name?

Answer (score 3):

`ls -l /bin/???` works for me.

Comment: you may want to add -a or -R, depending...

Comment: @Dave: I'd avoid the -R; in fact I'd recommend the -d flag...

Comment: -d specifically would omit files from the listing, so given the question, I thinks that's a bad choice.